# SalesForce - Sum records from another custom object

Tags: triggers, salesforce, apex-code, apex

How Do I Sum records from another custom object?

Hi.

I created a new custom object, called "referrals".

Every record in this object has a couple of fields and also an "email" field.

In my "accounts" object, I created a new field - "number of referrals".

In this field, I want to get the total number of referrals that has the same email address as the account.

What's the best way to do that? I'm a Wordpress and PHP developer, no previous experience with SF.

Thanks!

Comment: Shay, you might want to look at using a roll up summary field, firstly on your referrals custom object, create a Master-Detail Field to Account, And on your account object create a roll up summary field, Go here for more details. https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is without code.

If you make a Master Detail Field on Referral that looks up to the Account, you get what is called a MasterDetail relationship. This relationship allows fields on the Parent (in this case account) called rollup fields.

After that on the account you can create a rollup field for the sum of child referrals and add criteria to filter by email.

EDIT: Had to get my mind around this.

The above works great except when filtering by email. Here is a work around for this.

Create Referral Fields:

- Email (Email) = for your email
- Email Matches Parent (Formula, checkbox) = IF(Email__c == Account__c.Email__c, true, false)
- Email Matches Parent Stamp (checkbox) = this is a value we will populate with workflow

Create Account Fields:

- Emails with My Email (rollup, on Referral) = Count of records where Email Matches Parent Stamp = true

Create 2 workflow rules on referral:

- created, and any time it’s edited to subsequently meet criteria, Email Matches Parent = true. Make a workflow action, Field update, that sets the Referral Email Matches Parent Stamp to true.
- Do the same but a false, Field update to false

Now you will be free to create your rollup as desired. On account, create a new field called Referrals with My Email, set to roll up on the Referral object, Count, and where Criteria, Email Matches Parent Stamp = true.

This will give you a real time rollup based on that calculated field.

**Workflows:** https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=creating_workflow_rules.htm

**Rollup Fields:** https://help.salesforce.com/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en_US